# Spring Cloud Stream - Dependency Issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm trying to produce an avro byte stream onto my downstream topic like this:

```
producer.produce(mapper.writeValueAsString(obj).getBytes());
```

I am currently getting this error

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:433) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:287) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createRawProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:519) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createKafkaProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:420) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:407) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.createProducer(DefaultKafkaProducerFactory.java:374) ~[spring-kafka-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar:2.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.lambda$createProducerMessageHandler$0(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:356) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.lambda$getPartitionsForTopic$2(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:472) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.provisioning.KafkaTopicProvisioner.getPartitionsForTopic(KafkaTopicProvisioner.java:467) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:354) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.KafkaMessageChannelBinder.createProducerMessageHandler(KafkaMessageChannelBinder.java:150) ~[spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:225) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractMessageChannelBinder.doBindProducer(AbstractMessageChannelBinder.java:90) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.AbstractBinder.bindProducer(AbstractBinder.java:152) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.lambda$rescheduleProducerBinding$2(BindingService.java:319) ~[spring-cloud-stream-3.0.4.RELEASE.jar:3.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:325) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:370) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:368) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_261]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:321) ~[kafka-clients-2.3.1.jar:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avro/io/EncoderFactory
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.<init>(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:39) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.1.jar:na]
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.<init>(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:32) ~[kafka-avro-serializer-5.4.1.jar:na]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I can't seem to get the EncoderFactory Class, what is the correct versioning I need to have for my Kafka, SpringBoot, SCS, etc... Is there a discrepancy that this class may be getting overridden by a lesser/newer version?

Here is my Producer class

```
    public void produce(byte[] body){
        GenericMessage message = new GenericMessage(body);
        customProcessor.outbound().send(message);
    }
```

Channels

```
    @Output(ChannelsExtractor.MY.CHANNEL)
    MessageChannel outbound();
```

build.gradle

```
// in plugins
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'

// in dependencies
    implementation "io.confluent:kafka-avro-serializer:5.4.1"
    implementation "io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client:5.4.1"
    implementation "io.confluent:common-config:5.4.1"
    implementation "io.confluent:common-utils:5.4.1.0"

// Possibly here?
    runtimeOnly 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    runtimeOnly 'io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client:2.1.2.RELEASE'
```

Comment: Looks like you are using a non-compatible avro library. Thats where the `EncoderFactory` is coming from. Here is a sample application that shows some level of interaction with avro + confluent serializers: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/streambridge-samples/stream-bridge-avro

Comment: You probably have to adjust that sample to your use case. It is also using a later version of Spring Boot.

Comment: i hope you have the required configs in the application.properties or application.yml regarding the destination and source?

Comment: @chetank have the destination configured what do you mean the source?

Comment: spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=supplier;receiveAndForward;receive
    
    spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.configuration.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
    
    spring.cloud.stream.bindings.supplier-out-0.destination=sensor-1

Comment: @chetank I currently have this ```spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-channel.destination=MY.TOPIC
``` is there other properties I need?